# How can I stop git from moving my changes between branches?

Tags: git, git-branch

I am new to git, and coming from clearcase, I do not understand why the following happens:

Say I create a git private dev branch and do some changes to my files therein.

Now, I need to do some other unrelated work and checkout the master branch.

Git automatically brings my changes over from my private branch to my local master.

I find this very counter intuitive. The reason I had the private dev branch was because I didnt want my changes to go to other places till I was ready. Why is git moving them around without my saying so.

Yes, there is git stash, but once you have a couple of devs going in parallel or you need to switch often, its a chore to keep track of stashes. I would rather that the changes are not taken around with branch checkouts. And horrors befriend you if you forget to stash at a frenzied moment.

Am I missing some config that would avoid this?

Thanks a much!

Comment: Do you commit the changes to the private branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to commit your changes to the `private_dev` branch, before checking out master.

> I would rather that the changes are not taken around with branch checkouts.

Or even having two repos:

- one you never push (and in which you can commit in the `private_dev` branch)
- one in which you are pulling only the `master` branch (from the first local private repo), and then pushing to any remote you want.

That way, you never push by mistake your `private_dev` branch.

Comment: @ VonC I have not pushed the changes. The un-pushed changes are moved around when I checkout to master. In clearcase, my files in one view would never be moved to another unless done so explicitly. Should't that be the behavior in git too?

Comment: @zaphod if you commit your changes in `private_dev`, *then* said changes won't be moved around when you checkout `master`. But if you don't commit and not stashing... they are part of your working tree, and `master` won't touch them, which means you will still see those after a `checkout master`.

Comment: So, you mean that the working tree is not branch specific. It is common across branches? So unless I commit, the changes will be carried around. And this is not a bug in my git config.

Comment: @zaphod yes, as long as the master branch has no common files with the working tree, it won't erase any of the *private* files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I like to do:

```
git config --global alias.temp '!git add -A && git commit -m "Temp"'
git config --global alias.pop 'reset HEAD~'
```

Now when you want to leave your existing work on one branch and switch to another:

```
git temp
git checkout other_branch
```

And when you want to switch back:

```
git checkout original_branch
git pop
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you don't commit the changes to your private branch, so git sees them as untracked changes to the working directory. When you check out another branch, such as `master` and the untracked changes do not cause any conflicts, git doesn't do anything to modify them. This is a good thing because otherwise you could overwrite work that you have been doing.

In order to avoid this, be sure to run `git add` and `git commit` before doing a `git checkout` to change branches. Alternatively, you can use `git stash` to stash your changes as a temporary commit. When you return to your private branch with a checkout, run `git stash apply` to retrieve your previous changes or `git stash pop` to retrieve them and remove them from the stash stack.